# Linq syntax Contains

Tags: c#, linq

Linq syntax

Have a tag table: data contains tagName dogs, dog, cat

1    `string[] test1 = new[] { "dogs", "dog" };`

Compare test1 with tag table and return list of tags not in a test1 result: cat

```
var item1= Tags.Where(x => !test1.Contains(x.TagName)).ToList();
```

result "cat" correct

2. `string[] test2 = new[] { "dogs", "dog", "cat", "bird" };`

how do I compare test2 with tag table and return new items found in the test2 result should be bird.

```
var item2= test2.Where(x => !Tags.Contains(test2)).ToList(); XX fails here?
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried to use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx) method?

Comment: your question not so clear, what exactly do you want to achieve

Comment: "XX fails here?" What do you mean fails?

Comment: the syntax fails, doesnt compile. I want to comparing test2 values with tag table values. want to return all new items found in the test2 string array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
            //Datasource
            string[] Tags = { "dogs", "dog", "cat" };
            string[] test2 = new[] { "dogs", "dog", "cat", "bird" };

            var result = test2.Except(Tags);
```

If you're really interested in doing it with Contains, then you can do like this:-

```
var result = test2.Where(x => !Tags.Contains(x));
```

Comment: If I use contain syntax you provided it gives me a compilation error "cannot convert from string to Models.Tags? Tags is a table any ideas why?

Comment: You need to show the Type of 'Tags'. In my case I am using String array as my data source thus Contains is expecting a string value for comparison (x is value of test2 array in loop). The problem with your code is you are passing directly the table 'Tags' and not the property to be compared. Please pass the actual propert in Tags table which is holding the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Any()`:

```
var item2= test2.Where(x => Tags.Any(t=> !t.Contains(x))).ToList();
```